# calculating the resolution of a matplotlib graph depending on the numbers of rows to be plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I'm making a carpetplot on python using matplotlib's imshow. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

DATA = np.array([[0,0,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 9,0,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,0,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,0,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0],[ 0,3,0,1,2,4,5,5,4,3,2,0] ])

#plt.imshow(DATA, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.bwr)
DATA.shape

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.5,6),dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plot = ax.imshow(DATA, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.rainbow)


cb = fig.colorbar(plot)
xlabel = ax.set_xlabel('Days')
ylabel= ax.set_ylabel('bla bla bla')
fig.savefig('carpet_test.png',bbox_extra_artists=[xlabel], bbox_inches='tight')
```

The output is this:

[image: carpetplot with long DATA]

But if I shorten DATA and use the same code, the output is:

[image: carpetplot with short DATA]

The only difference between 1 and 2 is the length of `DATA`. The question is, how can I calculate the `figsize` used by `plt.figure` so each pixel or `DATA`point has the same width and height?

The width of the graph should always be the same, and the width of `DATA` won't change, only it's height.

Comment: You should be able to simply save `dshape=DATA.shape`, set a size for a single pixel (e.g. `pixsize=0.1`), get a figure size (`figsize=np.array(dshape)*pixsize`) and then pass it to `plt.figure` adding some extra space for the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by @Francesco-montesano, I came up with a solution. Its not perfect, but it works:

```
dshape=DATA.shape[0]
pixelsize = 0.8
figsize=np.array(dshape)*pixelsize



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.5,figsize),dpi=300)
```

with it, I dynamically adapt the height of the graph.